# Error:(69, 20) error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity

Tags: java, android, project, oncreate, main-activity

I am creating a simple app. I am running into one problem to finalize the app.

I am trying `onclick` image WebView in tabbed view.

However, only the first button opens the scanner. The second button does not do anything.

This is my current code from `MainActivity.java`:

```
package in.radioactiveenterprise.watchout;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    private static ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click();

    }
    public void click()
    {
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewz);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent("in.radioactiveenterprise.watchoutt1.Main2Activity");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1)
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2)
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 3);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "FASTBOOK";
                case 1:
                    return "TIMELINE";
                case 2:
                    return "FARMBOOK";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You literally have two methods `onCreate` with same arguments. That's can't be like that. Merge them in one.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `MainActivity`  remove below method

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    click(); // add this into your Primary onCreate method.

 }
```

Note: You can not use the same method with same Arguments in one class.

you can use bellow method if  your activities created with
 the attribute android.R.attr.persistableMode.

> Same as onCreate(Bundle) but called for those activities created with
>   the attribute android.R.attr.persistableMode set to
>   persistAcrossReboots.
>
> persistentState - if the activity is being re-initialized after
>   previously being shut down or powered off then this Bundle contains
>   the data it most recently supplied to outPersistentState in
>   onSaveInstanceState. Note: Otherwise it is null.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    click();

}
```

Remove the `click()` method and add into main `onCreate()`:

REMOVE ALL:

```
private static ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    click(); //add this on onCreate

}
```